# Executing a query using sum, count, group by and multiple left join MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables 1.user, 2.project_questions, 3.votings.

```
id project_id user_id question
 1        593     308 Hello Question?
 2        593     308 This is Another Question?
 3        593     308 sdssds
 4        593     308 asdsd
 5        593     308 dsfdsfsdfsfsdfs
 6        593     308 nro
 7        593     308 dsfsdfsdfsdf
 8        593     308 zxzx
 9        593     308 zxzxasasasasasasasas
10        593     308 zxzxasasasasasasasasfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfsdf
11        593     308 fdfdsf
12        593     308 saddsadsad
13        593     308 ghvhgvhg
```

**This is my query.**

```
SELECT `project_questions`.*, count(votings.vote) as vote, 
 sum(case when votings.yes=1 then 1 else 0 end) as yes, 
 sum(case when votings.no=1 then 1 else 0 end) as no, 
 `user`.`image`, `user`.`user_name`, `user`.`last_name` FROM
(`project_questions`) LEFT JOIN `votings` ON  
`votings`.`question_id`=`project_questions`.`id` LEFT JOIN `user` ON 
`user`.`user_id`=`project_questions`.`user_id` WHERE
`project_questions`.`project_id` = '593' GROUP BY `votings`.`question_id`
```

[image: votings table![][2]]

And user tables has three fields like user_id, first_name, username.
Expected results.

1. Question with it's yes and no votes and total votes. ex.

[image: This is my result]

But sometimes some questions not displayed.

Comment: Query looks fine to me, you might need to include a copy of your data (from mysqldump). Otherwise stupid suggestion but make sure its not on the next page of the result set.

Comment: Can you please check the project_question table( first image), there is a question whose id is 13 isn't displayed (in last image)? Last screenshot is MySQL result. I want to display all questions with it's votes.

Comment: Please check myssql fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40fed0/1

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40fed0/4/0 -- if not please provide sample expected output.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Actually I made a mistake on group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer confirmed in comments, was to group on project_questions.id instead of votings.question_id

```
SELECT
  project_questions.*,
  count(votings.vote) as vote,
  sum(case when votings.yes=1 then 1 else 0 end) as yes,
  sum(case when votings.no=1 then 1 else 0 end) as no,
  user.first_name,
  user.last_name
FROM
  project_questions
  LEFT JOIN votings ON votings.question_id=project_questions.id
  LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id=project_questions.user_id
WHERE project_questions.project_id = '593'
GROUP BY project_questions.id
```